# I keep on getting TypeError: v2.CurrentTaskForce is not a function

Tags: angularjs, typeerror

Left hand side of the page is displaying list of task force.
On click of the list item related data is to be displayed on right hand side.
When I click on the list item, first time it works fine. It displays the task force name as a header in right hand side panel. When I click on another list item it gives TypeError: v2.CurrentTaskForce is not a function

```
    var VirtualDir = GetVirtualDirectory();

    angular.module('MyApp',[])
    .controller('TaskForceController', function ($scope, TaskForceService) { // inject taskforce service
        $scope.TaskForceList = null;
        //$scope.CurrentTaskForce = {}

        TaskForceService.GetTaskForceList().then(function (d) {
            $scope.TaskForceList = d.data;
        }, function () {
            alert('failed');
        });

        $scope.CurrentTaskForce = function (item) {
            angular.forEach($scope.TaskForceList, function (value, index) {
                value.IsActive = false ;
            })
            item.IsActive = true;
            alert("s");
            $scope.CurrentTaskForce = item;
        }

    })
    .factory('TaskForceService', function ($http) { //here factory is created which is a populer way to create and configure services
        var fac = {};
        fac.GetTaskForceList = function () {
            return $http.get(VirtualDir + '/TaskForce/GetMyTaskForce/');
        }
        return fac;
    });



<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TaskForceController as tf">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" >
                <%--                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>--%>
                <li ng-repeat="item in TaskForceList" ng-class="{active: item.IsActive == true}" ng-click="CurrentTaskForce(item)" ><a href="#" >{{item.TaskForce}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 co-md-9" style="left:20%">
            <div class="panel panel-default" ">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <p class="panel-title">{{CurrentTaskForce.TaskForce}}</p>
                    <!--ng-repeat="curritem in CurrentTaskForce"-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While copying item to CurrentTask force instead of

```
$scope.CurrentTaskForce = item;
```

I used

```
angular.copy(item, $scope.CurrentTaskForce);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because CurrentTaskForce is defined as a function and a variable in same controller. Please use a different name for either.